# Should BFF(Backend for frontend) contain business logic?

Tags: architecture, backend

The idea of BFFs is to optimize backend for a **particular front-end experience**.

With that said. The question:

Should BFF's contain business logic?

Comment: it depends on application IMO. Some business logic may be needed in BFF as well. Although most businedd logic should be on models

Comment: Should I repeat the logic if i need other BFF(for mobile e.g) for the same application?

Comment: If you find you need to repeat logic then transfer it to a custom class or model and re-use it on several BFFs